# Column Names from Select Statement

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a sales table:

> Customer, Product, Sales, Date

Not every customer has bought every product, and some customers have bought the same product multiple times.

I would like to create a matrix where the column names are distinct(Product) and the first column is filed with distinct(Customer). The matrix would be zero-filed and would have a 1 where the customer bought that product.

I can grab the column names and build it with a very long create table statement, but this can't be the best way. Any ideas?

There are about 40,000 customers and 10,000 products

Comment: it is a PIVOT you're trying to do, not sure this is supported by netezza

Comment: Do you really want 10,000 columns? That's not going to be very easy on the eyes.

Comment: I want to use it as input to matrix factorization, similar to Netflix or Amazon's recommendation engine

Comment: Start with this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+dynamic+pivot I'm not sure which standard RDBMS Netezza most closely resembles, so I don't know if any of the answers in that search will be usable in your situation. Even they aren't directly equivalent, there may still be some good nuggets to point you in the right direction, in terms of the logic used.

Comment: Netezza will not support more than 1600 columns in a table or view, so you won't be able to instantiate such a matrix with a column for every distinct product.